# Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException: Token request failed

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online

I have the following CSOM code:-

```
using (ClientContext context = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(RisksiteUrl, clientId, clientSecret, AzureEnvironment.Production))
```

it was working well for around 1 year, but starting from yesterday the above code will raise this exception:-

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException: Token request failed. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server
returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Please check if the client secret has expired or not?

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for the reply,, i already check it and still it has the expiry date on july 2021..

Comment: @GauravMantri i also opened a ticket with Microsoft and they mentioned that this is something they do not support !!

Comment: Interesting! A few things you could do: 1) If possible, trace the request through Fiddler and see what's being sent and received across the wire. That should give you more idea about the error 2) I'm not sure if this is the right Github repository (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet) but you can find the correct repository and open up an issue there.